# Can I add a page tab app to a differenrt App profile page?

Tags: tabs, profile, facebook-apps

I wanted to know if I can add a page tab app I created to a different App profile page like I can add it to regular pages on Facebook. I can't see all my app profile pages(only regular pages are listed) when I click under a profile app page the link "Add to My Page".

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by visiting a link:

```
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?pages=1&api_key=APP_ID
```

This will bring you list of all pages (including application pages) you own, or you can specify directly which page should be used to add application to:

```
http://facebook.com/add.php?pages=1&api_key=APP_ID&page=PAGE_ID
```

Comment: is there a way to add a page tab app to a Personal Profile Page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using Graph SDK (in kind of background, silent mode - avoiding the user interaction), then you need to make a call like this

You need to get the manage_pages permission first, and then

```
if (accessToken) {
   var data = {
       "access_token": accessToken,
       "app_id":applicationId
   }
   FB.api("/" + pageId + "/tabs", 'post', data, function(response) {
       //success or failure, check it out
   });
}
```

It will install the application on your application profile as a tab :)

Hope it will help.

Comment: Requesting permissions isn't really way to avoid user interaction!

Comment: It is not the way to avoid **user interaction**, but if you have the proper permission granted, you can avoid the visual popup to allow users to install the app on a page. Its just automating the process of installing a tab in Graph way.